# Let $a$, $b$, and $c$ be elements of a commutative ring, and suppose $a$ is a unit. Prove that $b$ divides $c$ if and only if $ab$ divides $c$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-writing

Let $a$, $b$, and $c$ be elements of a commutative ring $R$, and suppose $a$ is a unit. Prove that $b$ divides $c$ if and only if $ab$ divides $c$.

Okay so here is the proof I came up with. *Please* be as critical as possible of the proof I need to have a very rigid understanding of this concept.

($\Rightarrow$)
Since $b\mid c$ then there exists some $n\in R$ such that $bn = c$.

Since $a$ is a unit we can rewrite this as $abna^{-1} = c$.

Thus we know that $na^{-1}$ is an element of $R$, so rename it as $x$.

So $abx = c$. Therefore $(ab)x =c$. Thus $ab\mid c$.

($\Leftarrow$)
Assume $ab\mid c$, then there exists some integer $x\in R$ such that $abx = c$.

Now since $a$ is a unit we can conclude that $abx = bx$, therefore $bx = c$, so $b\mid c$.

Comment: In your last lines: how do you come to $abc=bx$ on base of $abx=c$? Btw, the equality $abx=c$ tells us immediately that $b\mid c$. If $r_1\cdots r_k=c$ then every $r_i$ divides $c$. You don't need the fact that $a$ is a unit there. Also you should mention where it is used that $R$ is commutative (e.g. when you are saying that $abna^{-1}=bn=c$).

Comment: There it was a typo I have corrected my mistake, okay thank you for the input....I will post a revised version of the proof shortly

Comment: -->
Since b/c then there exists some n that is an element of the ring R, such that bn = c.

Since a is a unit and the ring R is commutative we can rewrite this as abna^-1 = c.

Thus we know that na^-1 is an element of R, so rename it as x.

So abx = c. Therefore, by commutativity, (ab)x =c. Thus ab/c.

<--
Assume ab/c, then there exists some integer x in R such that abx = c.

Now we can conclude that abx = b(ax), and we know that axis an element of R, therefore b/c.

Comment: "some integer $x\in R$...." Elements of $\mathbb Z$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $(\Rightarrow)$ part is good.

The $(\Leftarrow)$ part is wrong, unfortunately. You can't say that $abx=bx$.

> Assume $ab\mid c$; then, for some $x\in R$, $(ab)x=c$ and so $a(bx)=c$. Then $b(ax)=c$ and therefore $b\mid c$.

Note that this part doesn't require $a$ is a unit.